# Exportar de tabela html para excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-excel

Estou tentando exportar uma tabela em html para arquivo em Excel.
Este [plugin jquery](https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport) funciona quase que perfeitamente pra mim.

Meu problema é com a acentuação, que vem para o excel com caracteres estranhos. Alguma dica de como resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Verifique em https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport/blob/master/excellentexport.js na linha 19 e você saberá o motivo.

Comment: Eu vi que lá estão alguns caracteres, mas não saberia onde colocar os com acento. Tentei no começo mas não foi, vou testar a resposta do @Filipe.Fonseca

Comment: @2madera Alguma dica de como colocar uma lista de caracteres que funcione no plugin?

Comment: Experimenta mudar a codificação da página html para iso-8859-1 e adicionar os caracteres no javascript conforme a resposta abaixo. O Office usa texto em ANSI por padrão.

Comment: Não resolveu. Tentei colocar uma meta tag charset com valor iso-8859-1 na linha 87, na variavel template, mas também não funcionou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No arquivo [Excellentexport.js](https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport/blob/master/excellentexport.js),nesta linha:

```
var template = {excel: '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'}
```

Adicione `<meta charset="UTF-8">` dentro do `<head></head>`

Ficando assim:

```
var template = {excel: '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'}
```

Se o seu hmtl for `UTF-8`, claro

Comment: Funcionou! Eu tinha colocado outro charset e esqueci de testar o utf-8. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Função simples que fiz com esse intuito.

```
//adicionar a classe 'remove' em elementos que não devem aparecer no excel
//(inclusive em inputs type='hidden')
function exportaExcel(id,nome){ //id da <table> e nome do arquivo a ser gerado
    var hoje = new Date();
    var data = ('0'+hoje.getDate()).slice(-2)+"-"+('0'+(hoje.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+"-"+hoje.getFullYear();

    var nome_arquivo = nome+"_"+data+".xls"; //nome final do arquivo
    var meta = '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
    var html = $("#"+id).clone();

    html.find('.remove').remove();
    html.find('a').each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        $(this).after(txt).remove();
    });
    html.find('input, textarea').each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br>");
        $(this).after(txt).remove();
    });
    html.find('select').each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $(this).after(txt).remove();
    });
    html.find('br').attr('style', "mso-data-placement:same-cell");
    html = "<table>"+html.html()+"</table>";

    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,'+encodeURIComponent(meta+html);
    var a = $("<a>", {href: uri, download: nome_arquivo});
    $(a)[0].click();
}
```

Você pode chamar a função ao clicar em um botão por exemplo:

```
$("#botao_exportar").click(function(e){
    exportaExcel("id_tabela", "nome_arquivo");
});
```

Algumas observações:

- Requer jQuery (embora com poucas modificações é possível utilizar sem)
- Até onde testei só funciona no Chrome, creio que com certas adaptações deve ser possível utilizar em outros navegadores.
- Adicionar a classe "remove" em elementos da tabela que não devem aparecer no Excel.
- Modificar a variável "nome_arquivo" conforme sua necessidade (no meu caso adicionei a data de hoje para fins de relatórios).
- A função substitui inputs, textareas e selects por seus respectivos textos.