# Função para exportar tabela em html e php para Excel

Tags: php, html, microsoft-excel, aplicação-web

A função realmente funciona no Chrome, mas estou com um problema para fazer ela funcionar no IE e no Firefox e preciso que exporte em Excel para esses dois browsers, para um projeto. Quais seriam as alterações necessárias? Já tentei usar o `ExecCommand` para o IE e não deu em nada. Alguém tem uma ideia do que falta para o pleno funcionamento da função?

Me baseei na função da respota para a seguinte pergunta:

[Exportar de tabela html para excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8855/exportar-de-tabela-html-para-excel/214121#214121)

Não tenho ideia de como fazer uma função que exporte uma tabela em HTML e PHP e não a acho em lugar algum.

Essa função eu consigo exportar a tabela com sucesso para Excel mas apenas no Chrome, já no IE e Firefox não tem resultado. E preciso ter o recurso de nomear o arquivo exportado intacto também.

Código da função utilizado:

```
//a classe 'remove' em elementos que não devem aparecer no excel
//(inclusive em inputs type='hidden')
//id da <table> e nome do arquivo a ser gerado

function exportaExcel(id,nome){ 
    var hoje = new Date();
    var data = ('0'+hoje.getDate()).slice(-2)+"-"+('0'+(hoje.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+"-"+hoje.getFullYear();

    var nome_arquivo = nome+"_"+data+".xls"; //nome final do arquivo
    var meta = '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
    var html = $("#"+id).clone();

    html.find('.remove').remove();
    html.find('a').each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        $(this).after(txt).remove();
    });
    html.find('input, textarea').each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br>");
        $(this).after(txt).remove();
    });
    html.find('select').each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $(this).after(txt).remove();
    });
    html.find('br').attr('style', "mso-data-placement:same-cell");
    html = "<table>"+html.html()+"</table>";

    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,'+encodeURIComponent(meta+html);
    var a = $("<a>", {href: uri, download: nome_arquivo});
    $(a)[0].click();
}
```

Comment: Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código que está utilizando?

Comment: Editado. Essa é apenas a função que estou utilizando para a exportação;